# Whats wrong with these beginner style codes?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm a beginner and I was reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237241/what-coding-mistakes-are-a-telltale-giveaway-of-an-inexperienced-programmer. I didn't get few things.

1.Why writing something like this is frowned up on?

```
if (IsAManMan == true) { 
   Console.WriteLine("It's a MAN, man!");
}
```

2.what about this?

```
if (test) {
  return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

I don't write code like above. Should it be written this way: `return test`? or for readability I sometimes write it like `return test?true:false` or `return (test==true)? true:false`

Comment: I would argue that `return test?true:false` or `return (test==true)? true:false` are less readable than the if statement, but the most readable of all is `return test;`

Comment: Agreed with _chrisbunney_. The seemingly bad legibility of `return test;` is probably due to a badly chosen variable name, and putting more syntax around it won't improve matters. If it was, e.g. `return isAMan;`, things start looking different. I personally sometimes write `return isAMan == true;` to make it obvious at this spot in the source code that a boolean will be returned.

Comment: Just nitpicking here, but using the word "codes" in this way is not correct is it? I sometimes hear it and all I can think of when people say it is "Up up down down left right left right B A start".

Comment: @Niels: yes you're right, 'code' in the context of program source code is an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 12):

In this example:

```
if (IsAManMan == true) { 
   Console.WriteLine("It's a MAN, man!");
}
```

In most languages, `if` conditions always evaluate a Boolean expression, which means `IsAManMan` can only either be true or false. Comparing to true or false is thus unnecessary because it's **implied**. So we just write this instead:

```
if (IsAManMan) {
   Console.WriteLine("It's a MAN, man!");
}
```

And in this example:

```
if (test) {
  return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

Following the above example, this means `test` can only either be true or false, which is like saying:

```
if (true) {
  return true;
}
else { // If it's not true, it's false
  return false;
}
```

That's again unnecessarily verbose code, so we just

```
return test;
```

instead.

In the end, it's still a matter of preference and readability. For example, if you think `if (IsAManMan == true)` is easier to interpret than `if (IsAManMan)`, you can still write it that way and the compiler won't mind.

Comment: the compiler doesn't mind a lot of things that drive ME bananas. If `if (IsAManMan)` is unclear, it means you need to learn more about the language you are using.

Answer (score 8):

It's just a tautology. **If it rains** and **If it's true that it rains** is exactly the same and therefore, you can (or should) leave out superfluous comparisons, checks and returns.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases you're testing the value of a boolean variable. Because your value is already a boolean, there's no need to explicitly test against `true` because it's implied in the if statement (and similar constructs that contain a boolean test, like loops)

For example

```
if(isAManMan == true){ 
    //...
}
```

could evaluate to

```
if(true == true){ //answer: true
     //...
}
```

or

```
if(false == true){ //answer: false
     //...
}
```

which is the same as just writing

```
if(isAManMan){ 
    //...
}
```

In your 2nd example, you're examining the value of another boolean value before deciding what boolean to return.

Again,

```
if (test) {
  return true;
}else {
  return false;
}
```

could evaluate to

```
if (true == true) { //returns true
  return true;
}else {
  return false;
}
```

or

```
if (false == true) { //returns false
  return true;
}else {
  return false;
}
```

The if statement is redundant, because the variable already holds the value you want to return, hence this is equivalent, and preferred:

```
return test;
```

It's important to note though, that your examples are completely valid, however a good compiler will optimise them into the improved versions I gave, so ultimately it comes down to readability and convention. I believe the versions I gave are more readable and closer to the generally accepted conventions.

Answer (score 0):

These codes do same things. In my opinion, its just readability.

Answer (score 0):

Due to this being tagged language-agnostic:

There are languages where keywords can be used for variable names. In FORTRAN, this is a valid statement: IF IF THEN THEN ELSE ELSE.

If `true` is defined to be a boolean variable with value `false`, the proposed shorthand solutions are not the same as the more verbose ones. Neither if test, IsAMan, true, and false are not boolean values in the first place.

A real world example in Python 2.0

```
>>>True = False
>>>True
False
```

Tongue in cheek.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to return a boolean, and not the actual value of test for the 2nd case.

You could do

```
return !!test
```

in most languages, or something like

```
return bool(test)
```

which is more explicit and readable.